# Ideal number of properties/methods in a class

Tags: oop

What is the ideal number of properties and methods in a class? What considerations must be made in determining this?

Answer (score 4):

There is no "ideal number of properties and methods" but there are the [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) to which you should adhere if you want to have a good OO design.

But if you try to implement the Universe following the [God Object anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) the number is close to infinity.

Comment: +1 for the answer like mine, but you were faster.

Comment: thanks. It's all about speed with this type of questions, isn't it :)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is, 42.  It can be arbitrarily split between properties and methods.

Make some "private" because it's more intriguing when objects have something to hide.

Comment: +1 for '42' and another reason I prefer to keep to myself.

Comment: Please explain how you came up with this number.

Comment: Well me and a group of friends pooled our funds and created a really awesome computer. We then asked it for the answer to a really interesting question, and after a surprisingly long time it told us that the answer is 42.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be a question of numbers. A class should encapsulate a logical unit of code. You'll get a number of funny answers (one just popped in as I'm writing this ;) because it's kind of beside the point. If you have a concrete case however, you might want to put it into your question; there could be cases where a strange task may end up giving you a class with too many methods; that would probably be a sign of a design problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

There are really no ideal numbers. If a class is supposed to have hundreds of methods, and they logical behave to its domain, then use those methods.

Since good oop practices tends to maximize code reuse, then it's quite probable that a class can't reach a very large number of methods or properties without encounting the need to be splitted.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles you are most likely to end up with the most appropriate number. The number of members of a type will differ a lot depending on the purpose of this type. There is no magic number available that will fit all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

As few as possible, but no less, unless strictly necessary.